# Integrating $\int2\sqrt{t}\cos\Big(\frac{a}{2t+1}\Big)dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

Normally, when integrals look as daunting as

$$\int2\sqrt{t}\cos\Big(\frac{a}{2t+1}\Big)dt$$

I tend to plug it into WolframAlpha to do the work for me. With this type of integral (which I imagine to be non-elementary), I'd assume it can be "simplified" into terms of other common [non-elementary integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonelementary_integral) such as $\text{Si}$ or $\text{Ci}$ etc; which is the hope for this beast!

Surprisingly, Wolfram timed out / didn't understand so I was left to evaluating it by hand. However, I didn't get too far. The best lead I had was naïve substitution $u=2t+1$ to get

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int\sqrt{1-u}\cos\Big(\frac{a}{u}\Big)du$$

This nicely cleans it up slightly, but this may be a dead end. What are your thoughts?

---

**Edit:** As mentioned in the comments, I should probably explain why this came up. Perhaps embarrassingly, every now and then I take a stab at fiddling with the infamous [Riemann Hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis). I've transformed one of the sums of for the Zeta function in the critical strip into one with equivalent zeroes.

For some mysterious reason, it's been a goal of mine to find the equation for the most natural curve that passes through the partial sums of such summation. After many headaches, python programs, and tears, I've finally deduced a potential equation for (not the curve itself) but the *curvature* of such a curve. That curvature, is the integrand.

Comment: Did you mean that you made the substitution $u = 2t \color{red}+ 1$?

Comment: @VarunVejalla Indeed! Thanks for spotting that.

Comment: Unfortunately, you didn't mention why anybody would want to evaluate an integral like this one.

Comment: Did you try Weierstrass?

Comment: I tried substitution a power series for $cos(\frac{a}{u})$ and eventually turned the integral into $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{a^{2n}}{(2n)!}\int\frac{\sqrt{(1-u)}}{u^{2n}}du$$
which might be helpful as it seems closer to a power series which would be easier to integrate.

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+sqrt%281-u%29%2F%28u%5E%282n%29%29du) was able to compute the integral part of that equation, albeit with the help of some special functions.

Comment: For   $t=\frac{a-u}{2u}$
 the  integral becomes  
$$-\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}\int{\frac{\sqrt{a-u}\cos \left( u \right)}{{{u}^{5/2}}}du}$$
and using the binomial theorem for  $\sqrt{a-u} $ 

$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sum\nolimits_{n=0}^{\infty }{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{n+1}}{{a}^{3/2-n}}\left( \begin{matrix}
   1/2  \\
   n  \\
\end{matrix} \right)\int{{{u}^{n-5/2}}\cos \left( u \right)du}}$$                                                                Notice that $\int{{{u}^{n-5/2}}\cos \left( u \right)du}$ evaluates in terms of Fresnel integral